# VBA code to select value from drop down menu on sheet and go to column with same value as header on same sheet - Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

Code below is supposed to make cursor 'jump'to a column in range of A10:T10, when column header is selected from drop down menu cell A6.

```
Sub JumpColumn(Target As Range)
     If Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Address = "$a$6" Then
        Set Rng = Range("a10:t10").Find(What:=Range("a6").Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
        Rng.Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

As it is to run with another worksheet change event (PickName) it has been referred to in this code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
PickName Target
JumpColumn Target
End Sub
```

PickName is working but not JumpColumn, what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What is or is not happening?

Comment: Can you try `Target.Address = "$A$6"`?

Comment: @BigBen Nothing was happening! But SJR got it! Thanks both.

Comment: @ SJR - It worked. Thanks a bunch.